# Align Circle Buttons Vertically

Tags: html, css, button

I want to create a set of 3 circle buttons vertically aligned (see reference: http://i.imgbox.com/hAjYNmIq.jpg) but I can't get it done for some reason, the first button seems to cover the rest. I know this is a basic code thing but I'm stuck and I need to get this solved asap.

Here's a basic code for what I've got so far:

```
#pagination a {
    color: {color:Link Shadow};
    font: 700 1.000em 'Helvetica', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial!important;
    position: fixed;
    float:left;
    z-index: 999!important;
    bottom: 28px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:3px solid {color:Link Shadow};
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    width: 26px;
    padding: 13px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius:100%;
    margin-left: -245px; }
```

```html
   <div id="pagination"> <a href="#">Back To Top</a><br> <a href="/">Prev Page</a><br> <a href="/">Next Page</a> </div>
```

Comment: your question is unclear you want to vertical align the <a> that are present in pagination div??

Comment: If this is just an HTML / CSS question, make sure that is all that is included. You have a bunch of {...} in both. Two of your `href`'s are also incorrect.

Comment: put this in a jsfiddle please. half your code is not valid from an untemplated view.

Comment: Your first issue is that they are `position: fixed`. Therefore they're all getting positioned on top of one another. And they have `display: none`, so they're not showing up. And they have `margin-left: -273px`, so they're off the page to the left...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k9wzkqox/ start with that and give us something to work with.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle with the code, http://jsfiddle.net/d4snpkmr @Timmerz

Comment: @leftside http://jsfiddle.net/d4snpkmr/

Comment: @JeremyBlalock I used a script to make the buttons appear as I scroll down, so I had to use display:none, and the buttons should be fixed

Comment: all that should be in the original question, without knowing all parameters we can't help as much. You could try fixing `#pagination`

Comment: @Gonzier if you want them to be `position: fixed`, the best way to do that would be to put them inside a parent `<div>` that's position fixed, so you don't have to manually position each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating your HTML (incorrect `href`'s), here's what I've come up with. Your text will be overflowing because of your size constraints, though.
[And here's a Fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/ufxmf6fp/)

```
<div id="pagination">
<a href="#">Back To Top</a>
<a href="#">Prev Page</a>
<a href="#">Next Page</a>
</div>


#pagination a {
color: #000;
font: 700 1.000em 'Helvetica', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial!important;
z-index: 999!important;
background-color: #fff;
border:3px solid #00a;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
width: 26px;
padding: 13px;
height: 26px;
border-radius:100%;
display:block;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#pagination {
position:fixed;
}
```